# Maximizing a function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maximize

I am trying to Maximize this function with given constraints,

```
    Maximize[1200 + 6.95 x11 + 1.95 x12 - 13.05 x13 + 11.95 x21 + 6.95 x22 -8.05 x23 + 14.95 x31 + 9.95 x32 - 5.05 x33, 
 x11 + x12 + x13 + x21 + x22 + x23 + x31 + x32 + x33 <= 28000 &&
  x11 + x21 + x31 >= 6000 &&
  x12 + x22 + x32 >= 4000 &&
  x13 + x23 + x33 >= 2000 &&
  2 x11 - 4 x21 - 2 x31 >= 0 &&
  4 x12 - 2 x22 >= 0 &&
  6 x13 - 2 x33 >= 0 &&
  - 0.5 x11 + x21 + 2 x31 <= 0 &&
  - 1.5 x12 + x32 <= 0 &&
  - 0.5 x13 + x23 + 2 x33 <= 0 && 
  x11 >= 0 && x12 >= 0 && x13 >= 0 && x21 >= 0 && x22 >= 0 && 
  x23 >= 0 && x31 >= 0 && x32 >= 0 && x33 >= 0, {x11, x12, x13, x21, 
  x22, x32, x31, x32, x33}]
```

I don't know if this is my coding or just a big problem, but Mathematica is just giving me this back. Is there anyone who knows why?

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Notice you have x22, x32, x31, x32 when what you really meant was x22, x23, x31, x32 AND the folks at Wolfram steadfastly refuse to add a few lines of code to CLEARLY point out exactly which variable does not have an assigned numeric value or is missing from a list. When I change the x32 to x23 and make zero other changes Maximize instantly gives you the desired result.